# Need new method for identifying consecutive observations by specified intervals in r

Tags: r

I have something like the following:

```
  ID start value want
1  1   1.4   1.5    3
2  1   1.4   3.3    3
3  1   1.4   4.2    3
4  2   3.4   5.5    2
5  2   3.4   6.5    2
6  2   3.4   6.7    2
7  2   3.4   6.9    2
```

I want to count whether consecutive `value` observations happen one interval after another, where intervals are start + 1, within ID's. Essentially I am ONLY interested in whether observations come right after the observation before sequentially but in the NEXT interval, regardless of what interval that observation happens in.

For instance I was able to solve this by creating the interval columns (one after start, two after start etc), then using ifelse statements for whether `value` fell between one of the interval columns (`within_` vars as 1/0), and then returning the max sum of any possible left to right diagonal (`want`; gives the max times observation happened one interval after another) like so:

```
  ID start one_after two_after three_after four_after value want within_start_one within_one_two within_two_three within_three_four
1  1   1.4       2.4       3.4         4.4        5.4   1.5    3                1              0                0                 0
2  1   1.4       2.4       3.4         4.4        5.4   3.3    3                0              1                0                 0
3  1   1.4       2.4       3.4         4.4        5.4   4.2    3                0              0                1                 0
4  2   3.4       4.4       5.4         6.4        7.4   5.5    2                0              0                1                 0
5  2   3.4       4.4       5.4         6.4        7.4   6.5    2                0              0                0                 1
6  2   3.4       4.4       5.4         6.4        7.4   6.7    2                0              0                0                 1
7  2   3.4       4.4       5.4         6.4        7.4   6.9    2                0              0                0                 1
```

BUT the problem is that I have a ton of data, and it simply doesn't run. I am all out of ideas and would appreciate the help.

Data to play around with:

```
df<-data.frame(ID=c(1, 1, 1,2,2,2,2),
start=c(1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 3.4,3.4,3.4,3.4),
value=c(1.5, 3.3, 4.2, 5.5, 6.5, 6.7, 6.9),
want=c(3,3,3,2,2,2,2))
```

What I've tried and works somewhat for small data (but unfortunately sums the runs of diagonals rather than returning the max run of diagonals):

```
df1<-data.frame(ID=c(1, 1, 1,2,2,2,2),
start=c(1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 3.4,3.4,3.4,3.4),
value=c(1.5, 3.3, 4.2, 5.5, 6.5, 6.7, 6.9))



df1<-map(1*1:4, ~ df1 %>%
                   transmute(!!paste( "intervals", sep = "_") := start + .x)) %>%
  bind_cols(df1, .)


df<-df1%>%          mutate  (   within_start_one        =   ifelse( value   >= start &  value   <   intervals   ,   1,  0   ))
df<-df%>%           mutate  (   within_one_two      =   ifelse( value   >=  intervals   &   value   <   intervals1  ,   1   ,   0   ))
df<-df%>%           mutate  (   within_two_three        =   ifelse( value   >= intervals1 & value   <   intervals2  ,   1,  0   ))
df<-df%>%           mutate  (   within_three_four       =   ifelse( value   >=  intervals2  &   value   <   intervals3  ,   1   ,   0   ))

max_diag <- function(x) max(sapply(split(as.matrix(x), row(x) - col(x)), sum))
View(df_results)
df_results<-df%>%select(ID, 9:12)

df_results1<-merge(df_results, stack(by(df_results[-1], df_results$ID, max_diag)), by.x = "ID", by.y = "ind")
df_results1
```

Comment: 6.5, 6.7 and 6.9 are all between 6.4-7.4, therefore within_three_four(the interval I created)==1 for all three of these bottom three rows. Then, the two consecutive values would be 5.5 to any of these (as they fall in the same interval), so want=2 (max number of consecutive observations or the sum of this diagonal going from 5.5 to 6.5). It is just how I conceptualized the data but other methods are welcome and desperately needed, as this method takes a ton of memory.

Comment: I have added the code. No, basically each row I want to ask:
 "value, do you fall between any of these intervals starting from ```start```+1 and so on? if yes, great I will give you a 1 for that interval you fall in. THEN the next row:
value, do you fall between any of these intervals starting from ```start```+1 and so on? if yes great you'll get a 1 for that interval you fall in. THEN, if those 1's are diagonal from each other it means those two rows happened one after another. This is what I'm interested in. Hope that helps

Comment: but again, this method is not practical and takes a ton of memory, I'll see if the answers coming in work

Comment: only `dplyr`? or can we use `data.table`?

Comment: by all means use anything! I just need it to run and be valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?
How about this?

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
             start = c(1.4,1.4,1.4,3.4,3.4,3.4,3.4),
             value = c(1.5,3.3,4.2,5.5,6.5,6.7,6.9),
             want = c(3,3,3,2,2,2,2))

df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(
        interval = floor(value - start) + 1,
        consecutive = interval == lag(interval) + 1,
        consecutive = if_else(is.na(consecutive), lead(consecutive), consecutive),
        cumulated = sum(consecutive)
        )
#> # A tibble: 7 x 7
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>      ID start value  want interval consecutive cumulated
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <lgl>           <int>
#> 1     1   1.4   1.5     3        1 TRUE                3
#> 2     1   1.4   3.3     3        2 TRUE                3
#> 3     1   1.4   4.2     3        3 TRUE                3
#> 4     2   3.4   5.5     2        3 TRUE                2
#> 5     2   3.4   6.5     2        4 TRUE                2
#> 6     2   3.4   6.7     2        4 FALSE               2
#> 7     2   3.4   6.9     2        4 FALSE               2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: close but not quite, ID==2 here should have 2 cumulated (row 4 then row 5 is one interval after another)

Comment: currently running it, can you explain briefly the rationale for the interval variable youre making?

Comment: interval is the index of the interval after start that the value falls into. So 1.5 falls into the first interval after 1.4, 3.3 falls into the second interval after 1.4.

Comment: I'm running this and it appears to be good.. but any way I can return the max number of consecutive TRUEs in a row rather than the sum? for example if I had TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE, I want to return 2 rather than 3

Comment: ironically I found a bug in my code I used for small amounts of data, and it was summing the number of diagonals (i.e. 11 straight, a break, and then 15 straight=26) were being added together. I got the max number of straight TRUEs in your post and it was more accurate than my original... thanks a bunch

Answer (score 3):

An option is to reset value to the start (such that the new start is 0 for all ID), then count the number of consecutive intervals. Here is a implementation of this idea using `data.table`:

```
DT[, want := {
    d <- trunc(value - start)
    r <- rle(cumsum(c(0L, diff(d)!=1L)))
    max(r$lengths)
}, ID][
    want==1L, want:=0L]
```

Another faster implementation of the above:

```
DT[, rr := rowid(rleid(ID, cumsum(c(0L, diff(trunc(value - start))!=1L))))][,
    want := max(rr), ID][
        want==1L, want:=0L]
```

output:

```
    ID start value want
 1:  1   1.4   1.5    3
 2:  1   1.4   3.3    3
 3:  1   1.4   4.2    3
 4:  2   3.4   5.5    2
 5:  2   3.4   6.5    2
 6:  2   3.4   6.7    2
 7:  2   3.4   6.9    2
 8:  3   1.0   1.5    2
 9:  3   1.0   2.5    2
10:  3   1.0   6.5    2
11:  3   1.0   7.5    2
12:  4   1.0   1.5    0
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(ID=c(1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3, 4),
    start=c(1.4,1.4,1.4, 3.4,3.4,3.4,3.4, 1,1,1,1, 1),
    value=c(1.5,3.3,4.2, 5.5,6.5,6.7,6.9, 1.5,2.5,6.5,7.5, 1.5))
```

---

timings:

```
set.seed(0L)
nr <- 1e6
nid <- nr/4
DT <- data.table(ID=sample(nid, nr, TRUE))[,
    c("start", "value") := .(runif(1L, 0, 5), runif(.N, 5, 10)),
    ID]
setorder(DT, ID, start, value)

system.time({
    DT[, d := trunc(value - start)][, want := {
            r <- rle(cumsum(c(0L, diff(d)!=1L)))
            max(r$lengths)
        }, ID][
            want==1L, want:=0L]
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   6.80    0.03    6.85 

system.time({
    DT2[, rr := rowid(rleid(ID, cumsum(c(0L, diff(trunc(value - start))!=1L))))][,
        want := max(rr), ID][
            want==1L, want:=0L]
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.22    0.03    0.24
```

Comment: this is an excellent solution but still don't have the memory to run.

Comment: >500 thousand rows

Comment: for simplicity I made start a numeric in this data when in reality it is a date var. I'm converting it to numeric and seeing if that helps

Comment: I think it worked... changed my date variable to numeric and wala. Can't thank you enough

Comment: hey, your new want==4 is not quite what I want. that one should be 2, because 1.5->2.5 is one interval after another but 6.5 is not after the 2.5 interval.

Comment: also, when using it on my real data I am getting want values which exceed the total number of intervals possible for an ID, which should not be possible.

Comment: I think then what you want it’s just changing from sum to max(r$lengths)

Comment: no I use it if it is greater than 1.5->2.5. For example, if you had 6.5 then 7.5 then 8.5, want==3

Comment: Yeah using max should work then. What about the other comment about more intervals than possible?

Comment: I'll give some sample data when I get a sec

Comment: actually it looks like your edit did the trick! And it's incredibly fast, I was shocked with the run time

Answer (score 1):

Maybe somthing like this

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_example <- data.table::fread("ID start value want
1  1   1.4   1.5    3
2  1   1.4   3.3    3
3  1   1.4   4.2    3
4  2   3.4   5.5    2
5  2   3.4   6.5    2
6  2   3.4   6.7    2
7  2   3.4   6.9    2")
#> Warning in data.table::fread("ID start value want\n1 1 1.4 1.5 3\n2 1 1.4 3.3
#> 3\n3 1 1.4 4.2 3\n4 2 3.4 5.5 2\n5 2 3.4 6.5 2\n6 2 3.4 6.7 2\n7 2 3.4 6.9 2"):
#> Detected 4 column names but the data has 5 columns (i.e. invalid file). Added 1
#> extra default column name for the first column which is guessed to be row names
#> or an index. Use setnames() afterwards if this guess is not correct, or fix the
#> file write command that created the file to create a valid file.

df_example %>% 
  select(-V1) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  dput()
#> structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), start = c(1.4, 
#> 1.4, 1.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4), value = c(1.5, 3.3, 4.2, 5.5, 
#> 6.5, 6.7, 6.9), want = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 
#> -7L), class = "data.frame")

df_example <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), start = c(1.4, 
                                                                           1.4, 1.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4), value = c(1.5, 3.3, 4.2, 5.5, 
                                                                                                                    6.5, 6.7, 6.9), want = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         -7L), class = "data.frame")

df_example %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(row_numb = row_number(),
         current = value - start - row_numb,
         sum_if = if_else(current <1 & current > -1,1,0)) %>%
  mutate(want2 = sum(sum_if)) %>%
  select(-sum_if,-current,-row_numb)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>      ID start value  want want2
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1   1.4   1.5     3     3
#> 2     1   1.4   3.3     3     3
#> 3     1   1.4   4.2     3     3
#> 4     2   3.4   5.5     2     2
#> 5     2   3.4   6.5     2     2
#> 6     2   3.4   6.7     2     2
#> 7     2   3.4   6.9     2     2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>